# Twitter search API: get more results and since a specified date

Tags: search, twitter, twitter-search

I’m working on a simple search machine for Twitter where I want to extract all search results of an word (or words) since the dawn of time (or anyway Twitter). Is that possible?

I can only retrieve 100 results ordered by recently added tweets but I want to for example see how many times “facebook” has been twitted last month, last year, and so on.

I’ve tried this URL: http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?lang=en&since=2006-01-01&rpp=1000&q=facebook but it still doesn’t give me more than 100 results. I’ve read that the rpp parameter has a maximum of 100 but is there a way to “scroll” through the list and get all results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Offsets and pagination is probably your best bet